# How to recover from SVN checkout failure (network connection lost)

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

What do I need to do in order to recover from a failed SVN checkout? My internet connection dropped mid-checkout.

Comment: did you try to do the command again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ svn revert
$ svn cleanup
$ svn up
```

Comment: @acedanger: I don't think you need network connection for `revert` and `cleanup`, but certainly you need for `up`. The bottom line is - make a backup copy of your whole working directory and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform

`cd WC` + `svn up`